# The correct way to add a JavaScript in the functions.php

Tags: functions, widgets, javascript, html

I'm new to WordPress, and I've developed a code to load an iframe after a click in a button with some styles in a widget. But it is breaking the template's layout, and I'd like to know the correct way to add my funcions to the template.

```
<a id="fazer_pedido" href="https://example.com" onclick="document.getElementById('load-chat');
this.style.cursor = 'default';
this.style.opacity = '0.1';
document.getElementById('load-chat').height = '400px';
document.getElementById('load-chat').style.boxShadow = '0px 3px 15px #e4e4e4';
document.getElementById('load-chat').style.borderRadius = '15px';" target="load-chat">Load the iframe</a>

        <iframe frameborder="0" id="load-chat" name="load-chat" scrolling="0" style="overflow:hidden" width="100%"/>
```

I think I need to add the funcions to the funcions.php, but I don't know how to do that.

Comment: Breaking how exactly?

Comment: It is stopping several widgets and the footer to load.

Answer (score 1):

```
function my_scripts() {
    // Register the script like this for a plugin:
    wp_register_script( 'custom-script', plugins_url( '/js/custom-script.js', __FILE__ ) );
    // or
    // Register the script like this for a theme:
    wp_register_script( 'custom-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/custom-script.js' );

    // For either a plugin or a theme, you can then enqueue the script:
    wp_enqueue_script( 'custom-script' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts' );
```

Source :[wordpress codex](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/including-css-javascript/)

Comment: is there a way not to include files? as it is a simple js, I’d like to insert inline